# What wave-instead-of-serifs font is this?

Tags: font-identification

I've tried Identifont and Fonts.com's by sight identifier, and failed miserably on both accounts. Can you help me figure out what the font used throughout these ads is?

[Ad #1](http://assets.okazjum.pl/uploads/uploads/paper_page/1041/viewer_big_Fresh-00.jpg), [Ad #2](http://assets.okazjum.pl/uploads/uploads/paper_page/6802/viewer_big_01.jpg), [Ad #3](http://static.promocyjni.pl/uploads/brochure/cover/10953/big_2013_09_25_freshmarket_2013.jpg)

I keep feeling I know the font very well, and in fact thought I might have it in my collection, but have had no luck finding it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Diavolo by Jos Buivenga marketed via his [exljbris Font Foundry](http://www.exljbris.com/diavlo.html).

[image]